# Conflicting versions of celery and kombu while installing airflow

Tags: celery, airflow, kombu

I am installing airflow version 1.9.0  and getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ....
bcpmrstbssapp1 airflow: from kombu.entity import Exchange, Queue
airflow: File "/opt/xxx/lib/airflow/kombu/entity.py", line 9, in <module>
airflow: from .serialization import prepare_accept_content
airflow: File "/opt/xxx/lib/airflow/kombu/serialization.py", line 456, in <module>
airflow: for ep, args in entrypoints('kombu.serializers'):  # pragma: no cover
airflow: File "/opt/xxx/lib/airflow/kombu/utils/compat.py", line 89, in entrypoints
airflow: for ep in importlib_metadata.entry_points().get(namespace, [])
....
TypeError: can't intern subclass of string
```

I am using celery version 4.3 
Should I select a specific version of kombu ?

Answer (score 2):

Fix `kombu` version to 4.6.3

```
pip install kombu==4.6.3
```

Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-5240